# Pythonic way to convert XML attribute to float, or else get None

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, null, floating-point

My Python code is converting XML attributes in an `ElementTree` to appropriate values. How do I best convert a value in this dict to a `float()` if it exists, or else get `None`?

Best I have now is:

```
attr = etree_elem.attrib
self.radius = float(attr['radius']) if 'radius' in attr else None
...
if self.radius:
  # do stuff using radius
```

I dislike this because it's not DRY (repeats both `'radius'` and `attr`). I had code like this:

```
self.radius = float(attr.get('radius', -1))
...
if self.radius >= 0:
  # do stuff using radius
```

But (a) that only works when I know that a particular attribute value is otherwise invalid, and (b) it's not as "clean" to me as using `None` to properly signify that no radius was passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to get `None` without writing an explicit conditional.  The next best option may be to go with `float('nan')` instead of `-1` to make it harder to accidentally use it as a value.

```
self.radius = float(etree_elem.attrib.get('radius', 'nan'))
```

You can use `math.isfinite()` to test the existence of a value.  The `self.radius >= 0` test would also continue to work.

Answer (score 2):

Neither are that great.
And they are actually doing different things.
Take:

```
attr = {'radius': None}
self.radius = float(attr['radius']) if 'radius' in attr else None
# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

I assume you'd want to handle that the same way, otherwise you'd not have tried the other approach.
And so you could change it to:

```
float(attr['radius']) if attr.get('radius') is not None else None
```

Again this is in no way DRY, and so I'd instead make a new function say `float_nonnull`.
Where it's defined as:

```
def float_nonnone(data):
    if data is None:
        return None
    return float(data)
```

Which is good until you need the same with `str`, `int`, `dict`, etc.
But would also be WET if you pass the conversion function as an argument.
Unless you use `functools.partial`.
Which can result in:

```
from functools import partial

def convert_nonnull(convert, data):
    if data is None:
        return None
    return convert(data)

float_nonnull = partial(convert_nonnull, float)

print(float_nonnull(None))          # None
print(float_nonnull(1))             # 1.0
print(float_nonnull(2.2))           # 2.2
print(convert_nonnull(float, None)) # None
print(convert_nonnull(float, 1))    # 1.0
```

*Note*: it still errors on invalid input. Like `1a`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and pointing out edge cases. Personally, a separate function just to massage data is sort of the opposite of elegance that I was hoping for.

Comment: BTW, why not `if data is not None:\nreturn float(data)` and allow the implicit `None` of the function handle the other case?

Comment: @Phrogz You can do that, but I don't like an implicit `return None`. And to be a hobgoblin, it goes against PEP8 too.